# Input(float) gets converted to integer while saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

**The problem:**

When the information of the form is sent to the POST Action, the float variables lose their decimal point and gets converted to an `integer` instead of a `float`.

**Information:**

This is the class that contains the definition of the variables: `PUnit` and `CoinValue`:

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Precio por Jugada")]
    public float PUnit { get; set; }
    public float CoinValue { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I present a collection of this class, each one wrapped inside a form in order to be sent to the Controller indiviadually:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Device>

{...}
      <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}", "form", item.DeviceID))">
          <div>
              <input type="number" name="CoinValue" asp-for="@item.CoinValue" min="0" max="5" step="0.5"
              form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}", "form", item.DeviceID))" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="@item.CoinValue" class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
```

In the POST Action, the information of the `Device` gets saved:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Contadores")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Contadores(int? id)
    {
        var contadortoupdate = _context.Devices.SingleOrDefault(c => c.DeviceID == id.Value);

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(contadortoupdate, "",
            c => c.DeviceStatus, c => c.InitialAmount, c=>c.CoinValue, c => c.PUnit, c => c.SellType))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Contadores");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Contadores");
    }
```

**Results:**

When I insert a value of `0,5`, for example, it gets converted and saved into the Database as 5. Same as 4,5; it's shown as 45 and I don't know why is that. Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE:**

After debugging with Chrome I found out that the numbers in the form were being sent with this forma: `1.5` instead of `1,5` which causes the error. This ocurrs only in this View since I tested it on another one and it didn't change the format of the number.

[image]

The difference between those two forms is that the second one is defined just as an input:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StoreArea" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="StoreArea" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StoreArea" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

While the first one is defined as

```
<input type="number" {...}>
```

I believe that adding this ´type="number"´ property is the one that is changing the format of the input **but is my database who is not accepting this value as valid**, I believe.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you passed 0.5 as opposed to 0,5?

Comment: @AndyEvans. Noup, well, in my region we use a comma instead of a dot to define the decimal point

Comment: Your system doesn’t think so. That’s why it strips the comma away since it assumes it’s just a digit grouping symbol. Set a proper culture for the number format you want.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I would agree, but in another view I'm saving another property with the same format of a comma with no problem ): but I'll try to check what you are saying

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Also, when I type 0.5 it just happens the same thing, it gets converted to 5

Comment: Please show us (from Chrome Dev Tools) the **exact** payload you are POSTing.

Comment: @mjwills found something interesting (thanks for asking me to do that, I've learned something new now :) ) In the View I'm having problems the data is being send with decimal point, but in other form is being send with coma. this last one works fine. Will update the question to add pictures

Comment: when you use number as the type, it would not accept a comma.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Yeap, I remember I changed to this configuration in order to install SQL properly and now I'm checking what can I do to go back to use a 'regular' format instead of this comma hell.

Comment: try text instead of number. probably that accommodates comma as well. you could do the manipulation in the c# code.

Comment: I'm afraid if I do that I will have problems in others forms where this input is used for some aritmetical operations. I guess the best way to go is try to check what the DB is expecting as a number and what format does it want/need for decimals.

Comment: `DB is expecting as a number` The DB doesn't have a 'format' for numbers. The issue will be in the C# or the JS. Please show us the code you are using to write to the database.